# Miller-Rabin Recursive Primality Test

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, primes

I'm working on a primality test and have written a recursive function that returns the value of the function

> \$b^{q-1} \bmod q\$
>
> where \$3<= q <= 32000\$

Is there any way to speed up my function? It works, but takes a while to return the answer as \$q\$ approaches 32000.

Variables:

> `pow` = \$q-1\$
>
> `mod` = \$q\$
>
> `b` is a variable ranging from \$1 < b < q \$

If q is prime, then b will be = to q if not, b will be a "strong" feature of non-primality. See Miller–Rabin primality test.

```
public int fF(int q)
    {
        int b = 2, v = 0;
        while(b < q)
        {
            v = operate(b, q-1, q);
            if (v != 1)
                break;
            b++;
        }
        return b;
    }

 int operate(int b, int pow, int mod)
    {
        if (pow == 2)
           return (b * b) % mod;
        return (pow % 2 != 0) ? (b * operate(b, pow - 1, mod)) % mod : (operate(b, pow / 2, mod) * operate(b, pow / 2, mod)) % mod;
    }
```

Comment: That `return` statement...

Comment: @EngieOP yeah whats wrong with it?

Comment: @TheJackal It's a kludge. Hard to read/understand. Use the ternary operator for simple expressions only.

Comment: @TheJackal: Explain to me in a single sentence what that return statement returns. If you're struggling with this; realize that we have to read this code and tells ourselves what this code is intending to do, and we don't even have the benefit of knowing what we intended to write (since you wrote it).

Answer (score 5):

**Naming**

Oh my, what would **Mr.Maintainer** think if he would inherit the code... single letter variable names, methodnames like **fF**. He would have a hard time to figure out what is happening.

So let us clean this a little bit

```
public int fF(int possiblePrime)
{
    int baseNumber = 2, v = 0;

    while (baseNumber < possiblePrime)
    {
        int exponent = possiblePrime - 1;
        v = operate(baseNumber, exponent, possiblePrime);
        if (v != 1)
            break;
        baseNumber++;
    }
    return baseNumber;
}

int operate(int baseNumber, int exponent, int divisor)
{
    if (exponent == 2)
        return (baseNumber * baseNumber) % divisor;
    return (exponent % 2 != 0) ? (baseNumber * operate(baseNumber, exponent - 1, divisor)) % divisor : (operate(baseNumber, exponent / 2, divisor) * operate(baseNumber, exponent / 2, divisor)) % divisor;
}
```

**Style**

As many will agree, using braces `{}`, for single `if` statements also, is a have to.So let us use them and also let us remove the tenary expression and add an `int result` which we will return

```
public int fF(int possiblePrime)
{
    int baseNumber = 2, v = 0;

    while (baseNumber < possiblePrime)
    {
        int exponent = possiblePrime - 1;
        v = operate(baseNumber, exponent, possiblePrime);
        if (v != 1)
        {
            break;
        }
        baseNumber++;
    }
    return baseNumber;
}

int operate(int baseNumber, int exponent, int divisor)
{
    int result = 0;
    if (exponent == 2)
    {
        result = (baseNumber * baseNumber) % divisor;
    }
    else if (exponent % 2 != 0)
    {
        result = (baseNumber * operate(baseNumber, exponent - 1, divisor)) % divisor;
    }
    else
    {
        result = (operate(baseNumber, exponent / 2, divisor) * operate(baseNumber, exponent / 2, divisor)) % divisor;
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Refactoring**

Now let us focus on `operate()`

What you are doing, is always calling `number * number % divisor` so let us extract this to a method

```
private int calculateProductModulo(int firstValue, int secondValue, int moduloNumber)
{
    return (firstValue * secondValue) % moduloNumber;
}
```

The `operate()` method now looks

```
int operate(int baseNumber, int exponent, int divisor)
{
    int result = 0;
    if (exponent == 2)
    {
        result = calculateProductModulo(baseNumber, baseNumber, divisor);
    }
    else if (exponent % 2 != 0)
    {
        result = calculateProductModulo(baseNumber, operate(baseNumber, exponent - 1, divisor), divisor);
    }
    else
    {
        result = calculateProductModulo(operate(baseNumber, exponent / 2, divisor), operate(baseNumber, exponent / 2, divisor), divisor);
    }
    return result;
}
```

If we now extract the recursive calls out of the call to `calculateProductModulo()` we will see clearly what you have stated in your answer

```
int operate(int baseNumber, int exponent, int divisor)
{
    int result = 0;
    if (exponent == 2)
    {
        result = calculateProductModulo(baseNumber, baseNumber, divisor);
    }
    else if (exponent % 2 != 0)
    {
        int recursiveResult = operate(baseNumber, exponent - 1, divisor);
        result = calculateProductModulo(baseNumber, recursiveResult, divisor);
    }
    else
    {
        int recursiveResult1 = operate(baseNumber, exponent / 2, divisor);
        int recursiveResult2 = operate(baseNumber, exponent / 2, divisor);
        result = calculateProductModulo(recursiveResult1, recursiveResult2, divisor);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The code is calling 2 times the same method with the same arguements.

Let us eleminate the double calling

```
int operate(int baseNumber, int exponent, int divisor)
{
    int result = 0;
    int recursiveResult = 0
    if (exponent == 2)
    {
        result = calculateProductModulo(baseNumber, baseNumber, divisor);
    }
    else if (exponent % 2 != 0)
    {
        recursiveResult = operate(baseNumber, exponent - 1, divisor);
        result = calculateProductModulo(baseNumber, recursiveResult, divisor);
    }
    else
    {
        recursiveResult = operate(baseNumber, exponent / 2, divisor);
        result = calculateProductModulo(recursiveResult , recursiveResult , divisor);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The idea of fast exponentiation is corrupted by the following statement

```
result=operate(b, pow / 2, mod) * operate(b, pow / 2, mod)       #  (1)
```

instead of

```
result=operate(b, pow / 2, mod)**2
```

or

```
aux=operate(b, pow / 2, mod)
result=(aux*aux)%mod
```

It actually slows down the performance from \$O(log(\text{pow})\$ multiplication to \$pow-1\$ multiplications.  This is the performance of the dumb exponentiation algorithm (multiplying \$b\$ \$e-1$ times by itself. The performance gain comes from avoiding this second evaluation in (1).

Answer (score 1):

I've realized my problem, so I've changed

```
return (pow % 2 != 0) ? (b * operate(b, pow - 1, mod)) % mod : (operate(b, pow / 2, mod) * operate(b, pow / 2, mod)) % mod;
```

to

```
return (pow % 2 != 0) ? (b * operate(b, pow - 1, mod)) % mod : (int)Math.Pow(operate(b, pow / 2, mod)),2) % mod;
```

In the first return I was calling the recursive function twice and then evaluating the square. Instead, in the second, I call it once and then evaluate the square.  It runs much faster now.

Answer (score -1):

The code isn't tail recursive so you actually have to pay for the recursion with stack and function calls.

You can turn this iterative if you start at the highest bit and work your way down to the lowest. Computing `a^d mod n` becomes

```cpp
using std::int32_t;
using std::uint32_t;
using std::uint64_t;

uint32_t pow_n(uint32_t a, uint32_t d, uint32_t n) {
    if (d == 0) __builtin_unreachable();
    unsigned shift = std::countl_zero(d) + 1;
    uint32_t t = a;
    int32_t m = d << shift;
    for (unsigned i = 32 - shift; i > 0; --i) {
      t = ((uint64_t)t * t) % n;
      if (m < 0) t = ((uint64_t)t * a) % n;
      m <<= 1;
    }
    return t;
}
```

Note: `std::countl_zero(d)` is C++20 but available as compiler intrinsic before that (or in C) in many compilers. Modern CPUs tend to have opcodes that make this faster than bit-banging the result manually.

Note2: The code use the sign of `m` to extract the highest bit. can change that to extract bits at `i` instead of shifting `m`.

Note3: the code works for all uint32_t. If your numbers are small (<65536) then you could avoid the `uint64_t` casts.

Comment: It would be more instructive to stick with the language of the original question code (i.e. C#), rather than presenting a C++ function, I think.

Comment: @TobySpeight Sorry, if you know enough c# to rewrite the code then please do.